# unix vi editor: mapping ^J

Tags: vi

I am reading the book "learning vi editor"(linda lamb & arnold robbins 6th edition).
Page 115, the book has a command like this:

```
:map ^J xyz
```

The xyz part itself doesn't matter here, my problem is to make the `^J` part.

I have tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> can be used to escape Enter for example)
and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> directly

In both cases it doesn't work.

I am using vi editor inside FreeBSD 11.0, it isn't the vim (vi improved) .

----- Edit -----

Video:

https://vimeo.com/212400468

00:05 - map ctrl+K to do dd (delete entire line)

00:19 - try to do the same thing with ctrl+J, but it doesn't work because ctrl+J trigger a table.

00:25 - try again with ctrl+V ctrl+J. Also it doesn't work, triggering a table.

00:33 - try map exactly "^J"

00:44 - try with ctrl+J and it doesn't work as expected. It works typing the sequence "^J".

Comment: Hm. I would expect it to be `ctrl+v` `ctrl+j`. Have you tried caret j exactly how it looks?

Comment: Hi, zondo. I have edited the post inserting a video which include your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

That actually appears to be an error in the book.  The example is followed by this comment:

> In the previous example, even though **`^J`** is a *vi* command (it moves the cursor down a line), this key is safe to map because it's really the same as the `j` command.  There are many keys that either perform the same tsks as other keys or that are rarely used. However, you should be familiar with the *vi* commands before you boldly disable their normal use by using them in map definitions.

The usual inference for **`^J`** is <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.  But none of the vi's mentioned in the 6th Edition allowed one to insert a literal control/J in the text because that is the line-ending for Unix-like systems (vim will give you a `^@` null character when attempting to escape control/J, the other editors ignore that).  A *literal* "`^J`" does not work with the comment, because those characters are not a *vi* command.

You can make the *literal* "`^J`" work, of course.  But that was not the point of the example.  Likely the author intended some other interesting character and changed it for whatever reason.